# Weird behavior with ModalPopupExtender and/or UpdatePanel

Tags: asp.net, modalpopupextender

I try to figure out what is wrong with my code but I'm lost. I've a ModalPopupExtender, triggered in code behind by the onClick event link button. The FIRST time I display my popup, it works well and if I close my popup using javascript, it works and I can get my popup back by clicking on my linkbutton again. But, if I click the "Save" button of my popup (which save data and close the popup), I can't get my popup to display again. Even if I close my popup first using javascript and then calling my server side code to save my data, the result is the same, I can't display my popup again. Seems like the postback "break" it.

This popup is in an conditinal UpdatePanel and event trying to manually update the panel after the popup.show() method change nothing.

Finally, I checked what server sent back to the browser using firebug and I can confirm that I received only view state information (no UpdatePanel to update), even after calling panel.Update().

The behavior is the same in every browsers I tried and I've several modalPopupExtender like this in my application and it's the only one that behave that way.

Please help.

Comment: Can you share example code of the modal popup and save button event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doh ! It was in fact a little bug in MY CODE. It look like even if you go through your code for many hours, you still miss some details.

Sorry for the "spam"

Answer (score 0):

If I recall correctly, you have to rebind the events after that postback.  If you use the `live` method of binding instead of `bind` I believe it will work.

Josh

Comment: Thanks for the answer but that's not the problem because the event is called (I can see it using debug) but the popup isn't displayed.